# JavaFx TableColumn width in css using em unit

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

When setting the column width in CSS using `em` units as below and running the application, I cannot see the horizontal table view scroll bar and also cannot resize the column at run time from column header.

```
.table-column{
   -fx-pref-width: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically 1 em = 5 px. So 10em equivalent to 50px that will be unfitted with your tableView Object in JavaFX. So my suggestion  you can choose px format or can choose very small value of em that is fitted with your tableColumn in JavaFX.

Thanks

Comment: i want to zoom the layout using font size . all nodes response to new font size except table column son i want it's size to be relative to font size like other node's.